# jQuery Mobile page/navigation structure

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm currently evaluating the combination of jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. For my application, I need a kind of "inner application" navigation model: A fixed header that contains elements to switch between various contexts and functions, and the entire region below that depends on whatever function is selected. An example: The user selects a customer and can then switch between different data and statistics views concerning that customer. Alternatively, the user can switch between different customers while keeping the same view. Each function / view might again be a rather complex construct of multiple pages with its own navigation.

I think I understand the basic ideas of jQuery Mobile by now, but I'm unsure how to implement this "the right way".

- I could do this simply by coding the entire header with the navigation into every single page, but that feels like a really bad idea - lots of redundant code, lots of places to insert tiny mistakes that are very hard to find.
- I could try to add all the UI elements for the different views to a single page, hide them and only display the ones that belong to the current function. This doesn't feel right either - I suspect that the DOM would be really large and I suspect that this might cause various (performance) issues.
- I could try to create the contents of the page that depend on the function dynamically using jQuery DOM manipulation techniques. This sounds like a good idea, but the individual pages can be really complex, and I'm worried that generating lots of complex HTML code using JavaScript will lead to an unmaintainable blob of code.
- I could try to combine the approaches - code the individual pages in the HTML file and then somehow "link" them into the appropriate place using DOM manipulation - but I've never done that and I'm unsure if and how I can get this working.
- I could try to put the "detail" page into an iframe - would this work at all?

What is the best / canonical way of implementing this kind of application? Do you know of any tutorials or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just detach your header and then reattach it to your new page.  For instance:

```
$footer = $("#myfooter");
$header = $("#myheader");

$footer.detach();
$footer.appendTo('#newpage');
$header.detach();
$header.prependTo('#newpage');

$.mobile.changePage('#newpage');
```

Detaching does not kill all of your button handlers / etc.  You will need to keep track of what page you are on or look at location.hash to do different things depending on what page is being shown.

--Greg Frame
Thex Interactive
www.thexinteractive.com

Comment: Just to check whether it works I've done the opposite - $("#container").empty(), then $("#pagecontents").clone().appendTo("#container"). Is there a significant advantage/disadvantage to either approach?

Answer (score 0):

The first way is the easiest way to do it. That's the way i did it too. Also this gives u the freedom to add a button specific to whats in the browsing area for that page.

 
The second approach will have loads of extra calls which you don't want.
The rest of the approaches are not worth the effort.